# Getting this error "Invariant failed: A state mutation was detected inside a dispatch, in the path: todoReducer.1."

Tags: redux, react-redux

I tried everything like spread operator but nothing works.

Here is my reducer

```js
//state is an array of objects.
const initialState = [
    {taskName: "kkkkk", isEdit: false},
]
export const todoReducer = (state=initialState, action) =>{
    switch(action.type){
        case 'add'  :   
            
            const temp=
            {
                taskName: action.payload.taskName,
                isEdit: action.payload.isEdit
            }
            state.push(temp);
            return {state}
       default: return state
    }
}
```

Comment: You should also write the attempts you tried, and maybe paste also the error of the console

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The error message indicates that you are using Redux Toolkit - that is very good. The problem is that you are not using `createSlice` or `createReducer` and outside of those, in Redux you are never allowed to assign something to old state properties with `=` or call something like `.push` as it would modify the existing state.

Use `createSlice` instead:

```js
const initialState = [
    {taskName: "kkkkk", isEdit: false},
]
const slice = createSlice({
  name: 'todos',
  reducers: {
    add(state, action) {
      state.push(action.payload)
    }
  }
})
export const todoReducer = slice.reducer;
// this exports the auto-generated `add` action creator.
export const { add } = slice.actions;
```

Since the tutorial you are currently following seems to be incorporating both modern and completely outdated practices, I would highly recommend you to read the [official Redux Tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts) instead, which shows modern concepts.